Framing in front of insulation blanket
I am trying to DIY my basement reno and have a builder installed pink foundation blanket covering half the foundation wall (photo attached). I don't want to take it all off so framed in front of it.
Few quick questions (Location: Southern Ontario, Canada) :

Do I need to put Tyvek on exposed foundation wall before putting insulation in front of it?
Is it ok to put pink batt insulation in the bottom half of the frame and then vapor barrier bottom half and tape it to top half builder foundation blanket? Any downsides to the above approach?
Can I put pink batt in the top half as well and just not put vapor barrier on it (I understand it can cause condensation issues)?
How do I ensure batt doesn't fall in the cavity behind for bottom half (framing is a good 4" in front of the wall)?

Thanks in advance!


For question #4, to keep insulation from falling back you either staple the paper or foil insulation-backing to the framing, or you use friction-fit insulation cut to size like rockwool. I used rockwool and a thin wood board that I ran behind the framing so I could kind of pat and sweep any insulation back into the stud bay if I pushed it in too far.

For the vapor barriers, that is a tricky situation since you're talking about barriers in different layers of the wall assembly. My understanding is it is best to have no vapor barrier or only have it on the inner-most layer, to keep condensation out of the wall. I went with no vapor barriers and kept the wall breathable. Once you create a vapor barrier, you now have to deal with that layer as a likely point of moisture being trapped and condensing. How will you keep moisture from hitting that barrier, cooling and condensing?

Please take the [tour] and see [ask], then revise to ask a single specific question, reflected in your title. I'll save you some time: House wrap doesn't go inside the building.
